# Map cant be scrolled in iOS safari sometimes

Tags: javascript, safari, mapbox-gl-js

Example is [here](http://output.jsbin.com/qefexop)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Display a map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        * { margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing: border-box; }

        #map {position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 50%; bottom: 0;}
        #content { margin: 0 0 0 50%; background: lightblue;}
        p {
            padding: 50px
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

        <div id="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum facilis itaque
                officiis omnis porro quia quos vero? Architecto beatae dicta magni, minus non
                obcaecati quae quibusdam quis sunt ut, vel?</p> 
        </div> 


    <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGF2ZWxzIiwiYSI6ImNpdGN4Zm56MDAwNWEyeW8zcWFoaGNkbHgifQ.o_5rdc4PS-yJV8tkh8cyEA';

        var mapEl = document.getElementById('map')

        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map', // container id
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet location
            center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
            zoom: 9 // starting zoom
        });

         map.on('load', () => {
          map.on('touchstart', e => console.log('touchstart', e))
          map.on('touchmove', e => console.log('touchmove', e))
          map.on('touchcancel', e => console.log('touchcancel', e))
          map.on('touchend', e => console.log('touchend', e))

          map.on('movestart', e => console.log('movestart', e))
          map.on('move', e => console.log('move', e))
          map.on('moveend', e => console.log('moveend', e))

          map.on('dragstart', e => console.log('dragstart', e))
          map.on('drag', e => console.log('drag', e))
          map.on('dragend', e => console.log('dragend', e))

          map.on('error', e => console.log('error', e))
        }) 

        var mapTouchFix, tmt;

        if (window['Event']) {
          mapTouchFix = new Event('touchstart') 
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
          console.log('add scroll tmt')
          if (tmt) clearTimeout(tmt)
          tmt = setTimeout(() => {            
            console.log('scroll tmt')
            fixmap()
          }, 1000)
        })

        document.querySelector('#map').addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
          console.log('Ha touch start processed ON MAP')
        })

        function fixmap () {

          console.log('isDragPanEnabled' + map.dragPan.isEnabled())
          console.log('isDragPanActive' + map.dragPan.isActive())

           var p = map.getPitch()

          map.easeTo({
            pitch: p + 1
          })         

          map.dragPan.disable()
          console.log('dragpan disabled')

          setTimeout(() => {
            map.dragPan.enable() 
          map.easeTo({
            pitch: p
          }) 
            console.log('dragpan enabled back')
          }, 1000)

          mapEl.dispatchEvent(mapTouchFix)
          document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(mapTouchFix)
          console.log('fixed', mapTouchFix)
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some times after page scrolling user cant scroll map, only possible to scroll map after click on any button or on map itself.

If you cant reproduce it, try to scroll map while page is being scrolled and move map after scrolling is finished.

Reproducible in iPad mini, iPad pro, iPhone with v11.x iOS

I tried to modify CSS to remove anything that could cause such behavior, trigger map methods and fire `touchstart` events, nothing helps.

Also I implemented two fingers scroll for map in another example, but issue is there sometimes as well.

Some times after page scrolling user cant scroll map, only possible to scroll map after click on any button or on map itself.

If you cant reproduce it, try to scroll map while page is being scrolled and move map after scrolling is finished.

Reproducible in iPad mini, iPad pro, iPhone with v11.x iOS

I tried to modify CSS to remove anything that could cause such behavior, trigger map methods and fire `touchstart` events, nothing helps.

Also I implemented two fingers scroll for map in another example, but issue is there sometimes as well.

Comment: You should either include your code here, or paste it on a site that actually shows the code, not just the running output. (Like codepen or jsfiddle.)

Comment: Tx, your comment was very helpful. 
The reason i didn't paste code is that i was using phone to create a post, and it was extremely inconvenient to add it there for me.